# Refusal of UK visit Visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I applied UK visit from Dubai and My visa to visit Uk for one week has been refused and the reason given as below. Please advise what are the chances if i re apply and how to satisfy them. What is intervention of application reviewer on below highlighted. I am Pakistan national.**Can someone please tell what should we do about it and what should i submit to overcome this rejection again?**

> I have refused your application for business visit visa because i am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(S) V4.2-4.10 of Appendix V.
>
> You state that you are married with child, have been employed as supervisor since feb 2012 and earn a total monthly income of £1750. you further state that you spend £750 each month on living costs, give £100 to family members and have £2000 available for your one week visit. Although i note the £800 of savings and investments you have declared, **i do not find it credible that you would spend the equivalent of your monthly salary on a visit to the uk, now. i am therefore not satisfied that the purpose and period of trip is as claimed.**
>
> In support of your personal financial circumstances, you have submitted a bank statement with the balance of £3100. **i am therefore not satisfied that bank statement is an accurate reflection of your personal financial circumstances, which leads me to further doubt that purpose and period of your visit is as claimed.V4.2(a) and (c) of appendix V.**
>
> In light of all the above, i am not satisfied as to your intentions in wishing to travel to the UK now.i am not satisfied that you genuinely intend a short visit only to the UK and that you will leave the UK at the end of the visit.

Comment: Where are you a citizen of? What is your question. ("Seeking advice" is not a question. What is it that you want to do now?)

Comment: Hi i am from Pakistan. I want to reapply but how i can satisfy them?

Comment: please edit that information and the question in to your answer.

Comment: You mean reapply and edit information in new form?

Comment: err, not answer sorry, question on here. Please press the "edit" link just below your question, and add the clear question, and your nationality in to the text somewhere.

Comment: i believe now question is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My uncle was also refused a UK visit visa on similar basis. The official compute the ratio between the savings per month and the expenses that one is willing to spend (shown in the form of bank statement). Plus if there are dependents (kids in my uncle case) then they are even stricter. Adding your spouse earnings or savings might  make the case stronger and convince the issuing authority about you travel.

Comment: In my case advise what is the best i can do to make my application acceptable. i even paid for hotel and that money i will lose as well

Comment: You should not pay for hotel or book flight tickets before getting visa. Paying for a hotel may have arised their suspicions to look deep further in your case.

Comment: That mistake i have done already and now selling room. But Can you review my rejection letter and  please tell what should we do about it and what should we submit to overcome this rejection again?

Comment: So adding spouse earnings or additional savings is not an option? Other than that I dont know what could be done. Especially the rejection was based on the financial situation that is why making the finances better might help.